# Flattening nested field to array in Flask API

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, flask-restplus

I'm using `flask_restplus` to build an API.

I have two models:

```
model_barcode = api.model('Barcode', {
        'code': fields.String,
    })
```

and

```
model_product = api.model('Product', {
        'id': fields.Integer,
        'name': fields.String,
        'barcodes': fields.Nested(model_barcode, as_list=True),
    })
```

The relationship between `Product` and `Barcode` is many-to-many.

The API response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 15707,
        "name": "Jojo Leaf Eater - White",
        "barcodes": [
            {
                "code": "6009702666853"
            },
            {
                "code": "9317118010229"
            },
            {
                "code": "6009194082315"
            },
            {
                "code": "6009149569649"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However, since the contents of the barcode model are just a single field I want it to marshal like this instead:

```
[
    {
        "id": 15707,
        "name": "Jojo Leaf Eater - White",
        "barcodes": ["6009702666853", "9317118010229",
                     "6009194082315", "6009149569649"]
    }
]
```

How would I do this?

I've tried wrapping the call to `fields.Nested()` in `fields.List()` but that did not help.

If anybody has an idea of how to make this work, I'd really appreciate the help!

Thanks.

**Background Information**

Here are the relevant package versions:

```
Flask==1.1.1
flask-restplus==0.13.0
marshmallow==3.3.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.11
simplejson==3.17.0
```

**Database Classes**

Here are the definitions of the SQLAlchemy classes:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id                  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name                = Column(String(256))
    barcodes            = relationship('Barcode',
                                       secondary='product_barcode',
                                       back_populates='products')

class Barcode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'barcode'

    id                  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code                = Column(String(15))
    products            = relationship('Product',
                                       secondary='product_barcode',
                                       back_populates='barcodes')
```

**Alternative Implementation**

I have a working implementation using Marshmallow.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class BarcodeSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'code',)

class ProductDetailSchema(Schema):
    barcodes = fields.Pluck(BarcodeSchema, "code", many=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'barcodes')
        ordered = False
```

This does precisely what I want. However I'd really prefer to use `flask_restplus` models because they make the code for the actual API a lot neater.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done it easily like this

```
'barcodes': fields.List(fields.String, attribute=lambda p: [product.code for product in p.barcodes])
```